# Primefaces Autocomplete w/ POJO Converter - How to correctly create an unique display value?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete, converters

I have a Customer bean, mapped to my DB, that has `id` and `name` as attributes.

I need to implement a Converter in order to use the autocomplete with pojo component.

How should I implement the `getAsObject` method, when I want the display value to be `customer.name`?

There might be a scenario where I have 2 customers with the same name.

In this case, I can't just retreive a customer from the DB, I would need to use the `customer.id` attribute as the display value and that would look horrible.

What's your approach for this?